# Failed to load perf counters from the computer <comp name>

Tags: performance, windows-xp, iis-6, webapplicationstresstool

I am using the Web Application Stress tools from Microsoft to run some stress tests on a Windows 2003 IIS 6 server. I am running the WAS tool from a windows XP machine. I have been following this [tutorial](http://www1bpt.bridgeport.edu/sed/projects/cs597/Fall_2002/jishah/web_application_stress.htm) and when trying to add perf counters I get the following error :

> Failed to load the perf counters from
>   the computer \mycomp

Does anyone know what this means? how can I load perf counters? I would have thought that the perf counters I want are on the server I am testing rather than the local machine from which I am running tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution :)

Here's this italian blog. Basically it says you should copy pdh.dll into the program folder.
http://www.maurodalfreddo.it/archives/249/web-application-stress-tool-anche-su-xp

So here's what I did:

Download nt4pdhdll.exe from (you need the w2k version)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284996

Copy the contents (5 files) into your C:\Program Files\Microsoft Web Application Stress Tool directory.